# Access Controller function from AJAX in Laravel 4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel, even I am new to PHP. I am trying to access a controller function through AJAX, which will return some data. Every time when I run AJAX it shows 404 error. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Following is my code:

routes.php(now)

```
Route::get('/about' , 'HomeController@gtn');
Route::get('test' , array('as' => 'test', 'uses' => 'HomeController@test'));
```

Controller(HomeController.php) has these functions:

```
 public function test()
   {
        return 'Testing dude!!';
   }
    public function gets()
    {
        $data['stt'] = Mein::getstate();
        return View::make('/about',$data);
    }
    public function gtn()
    {           
        $data['shw'] = Mein::getCity();
        return View::make('/about',$data);
    }
```

My AJAX call(now):

```
 $.ajax({
    url:'{{route("about")}}',
    type:'GET',
    // data:'soni'
  });
```

I want to access `test` function of `HomeController`. I checked the call from browser, it shows 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call a controller directly (and definitely not like that!), but you call a url, or better a route (Laravel has **named routes**, it's good to use them):

```
$.ajax({
 url:'{{route("about")}}',  // or url: '{{url("about")}}'
 type:'GET',
 success: function(rxp){
   // handle response here
   // es. $('#mydiv').html(rxp);
  }
});


Route::get('about' , array('as' => 'about', 'uses' => 'HomeController@gtn'));
```

**Edit:**

> I want to access test function of HomeController

Then create a route for the test() method:

```
Route::get('test' , array('as' => 'test', 'uses' => 'HomeController@test'));
```

**Update after comment:**

I gave you blade syntax guessing you where using it in your template files. If you want to use blade, rename the file to filename.blade.php. Or else use php:

```
 url:'<?php echo route("about");?>',
```

Comment: @user3708421 edit your post and show your new code witch give you 403

Comment: Have a look at your page source - what URL is being called?

Comment: @Kryten : the url that is being called is : GET http://mediat.com/%7B%7Broute(%22about%22)%7D%7D

Comment: @user3708421 See updated answer, that url is not correct because you're not using blade as template engine (I thought you were)...

Answer (score 0):

```
var redirect_url = 'about';
        $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'about',
    data: { 'facilityid' : y , 'status' : val }
}).done(function () {
    window.location.href = redirect_url;
});

Route::get('about' , array('as' => 'about', 'uses' => 'HomeController@gtn'));
```